# Yii check if logged into Facebook every page

Tags: php, facebook, yii

**SOLVED POSTED THE CODE AT THE BOTTOM**

I finally got this working, but to be honest i guess i'm doing this totaly wrong.

**What i want:**

I want to get an check on my site if an user is logged into the site via Facebook. This must be done one every page, cause certain parts of the site need to only be accesable if you are logged in. Also i would like to put the data of Facebook into my Database.

**What i got:**

At the moment I am able to check on every page if the user has logged via Facebook into my website. I did get this working by altering the `init()` function in the `SiteController.php`.

This function now looks like this:

```
public function init() {
    global $facebookID; // Create global Facebook ID
    global $loginURL;   // Create global URL for login

    $currentURL =  'http://dev03.***.nl/app/facebook-popup.php'; // facebook popup url

    //Get Facebook ID if FacebookID isn't there the result is 0
    $facebookID = Yii::app()->facebook->getUser();


    if(!$facebookID){
        //If there isn't an Facebook ID
        $loginURL = Yii::app()->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'read_insights, publish_actions, manage_pages',
            'display' => 'popup',
            'next' => $currentURL . '?loginsucc=1',
            'cancel_url' => $currentURL . '?cancel=1'
        ));
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

The biggest problem is that my site load time expanded, but i don't know how to get this working in an other way. I'm guessing I would be able to put this test into an more load time friendly way.

**My question:**

How would i be able to decrease the load time, and program this the correct way. Am i able to make this as an function so that if i switch to certain pages there would be an check if the user is logged in via Facebook and show certain pages on the result.

**My second question:**

At the moment I check in my views/layouts/main.php if the global facebookID is empty or not to show the Facebook profile picture or an login button the following way:

```
<?php if ($GLOBALS['facebookID']) { ?>                      
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $GLOBALS['facebookID'] ?>/picture"/> 
<?php } else{ ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="login();return false;">
        <div id="login_facebook">
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl?>/images/buttons/facebook.png" alt="Facebook logo">
        <p>login met Facebook</p>
    </div><!-- #login_facebook -->
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

If i got an function which checks this for me I guess the load time would also decrease, or is this the only way to put if statements in layouts?

I know this is an big question, but i'm kinda new to Yii and I hope some of you guys would take the time to help me with this.

**SOLUTION**

With a big thanks to @DarkMukke i was able to solve this question. I changed some things around and maybe did some things that aren't the perfect way. But it works fine for me now.

To start with, i changed my whole thinking about the user authentication, and i removed the globals. At this moment the only first check the webapp does is if we got an facebookID and an user. This is to prevent access when the user deletes the rights in Facebook but is still logged in to the app and got the user status. This is done with the following code:

protected/components/Controller.php

```
public function init() {
    $facebookID = Yii::app()->facebook->getUser();

    if(!$facebookID && Yii::app()->user->getState('role') == 'user'){
        Yii::app()->user->setState('role', 'guest');
    }
}
```

So in `$facebookID` we store the facebookID of the user, if the user has revoked acces then `$facebookID` is empty. So we check if the user got the role `'user'` and if the Facebook id is empty. If so the users needs to get the role `'guest'`.

Then the login issue, Instead of using the main Controller for this i decided to make an new controller. I placed this in protected/controllers/FacebookController.php and it looks like this:

```
class FacebookController extends Controller {

    public function actionLogin() {
        $facebookID = Yii::app()->facebook->getUser();
        $accessToken = Yii::app()->facebook->getAccessToken();
        $loginUrl = Yii::app()->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'read_insights, publish_actions, manage_pages, email', 'display' => 'popup', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://dev03.****.nl/app/facebook-popup.php'));

        if($facebookID == 0) {
            echo '<script>
                    window.location="'.$loginUrl.'"
                  </script>';

        } else {
            $record = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('FB_id'=>$facebookID));
            if($record===null) {                
                $userInfo = Yii::app()->facebook->api('/me');

                $user = new Users;
                $user->firstname = $userInfo['first_name'];
                $user->surname = $userInfo['last_name'];
                $user->city = $userInfo['location']['name'];
                $user->email = $userInfo['email'];
                $user->FB_id = $userInfo['id'];
                $user->save();
            }

            Yii::app()->user->setState('role', 'user');
            Yii::app()->user->setState('FBid', $facebookID);

            echo "<script>
                    window.close(); 
                    window.opener.location.reload();
                   </script>";
        }
    }       
}
```

**Please note, i am calling this function in an popup via Javascript**

So what this does is:

First, get Facebook id, get access token and login url.

Then we check if we got an Facebook id, if not change the location of the popup to the login url for Facebook. This opens the dialog to get access and the permissions described in `'scope'` in the `getLoginUrl()` function.

If we have the permissions it checks if we got the user in the database. if not `$record` is `null`. Then we get the info of the user with `api('/me')` and post this in the database. If this is done we go on.

Then we set the role of the user to user and add an state called FBid with the Facebook id to use this later in the application.

When this all is done we close the window. And the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you have some ideas on what you are doing. so let me point out some tips.

First of all, if you are overriding the init in your SiteController, you will have to do it in every new controller, so you better overwrite init() in Controller, the class in /protected/components, that every controller is extending from by default, that way it really will be on EVERY page.

Second note, globals are a bad idea. They might seem usefull, but they are a pain to debug. In my opinion, globals should be removed from the next version of PHP.
So the correct way here would be to use [CWebuser->setState()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail), this way you can just check if the user is logged in or not. This gives you another usefull advantage. On first FB login you create a user with his data in your own users table, and for the UserIdentity you just use the FB check, and load the record where the FBid == your record with that FBid set.

So in short,

- when people authorize, create a record for them in your users table
- use the native user check, to check if logged in with the native cookie
- if not logged in compare FacebookId against your own records
- if no records, try to authorize them with Facebook popup
- to have the Facebook data everywhere, use [CWebuser->setState()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail), in your UserIdentity, dont use globals